# CDAP HTTP server plugin for listens incoming requests

Tags: http, hadoop, cdap

I am using cdap-sandbox-6.8.0.zip, do we have HTTP server plugin in CDAP for listens HTTP incoming requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all [Data Sources](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/464617561/Realtime+Sources) in the docs.

There is no HTTP server, only HTTP client.

You could host a web-server in your cluster that does accept requests and store them with an API, then use the HTTP polling source to read that data.

Alternatively, you could use the Kafka source, then deploy Kafka REST Proxy to accept HTTP requests that forward to a Kafka topic, which CDAP would consume